# Все ли запятые на своих местах?

Tags: пунктуация

И, даже, приближаясь к звёздам, помни, что всегда можно подняться ещё выше!

Comment: А какие вызывают сомнения? Здесь подобные "домашние задания" обычно не делают и проверяют, если спрашивающий не уточнит, в чем сложность. Хотя лишние запятые, похоже, есть.)))

Comment: Не вызывает ни одна. Хорошо. Я не знал ваших правил. Приношу извинения.

Comment: Первые две зачем?  После "И" и после "даже"?

Comment: @behemothus, благодарю!)

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос сформулирован вполне корректно - там ли и так ли расставлены запятые.

Обе запятые, обособляющие частицу "даже", не нужны.

Но первую ещё можно оспорить; автор предложения может настаивать, что союз "и", открывающий предложение, относится к глаголу "помни". Если же не относится, то формально считаем, что союз принадлежит деепричастному обороту.

Вторая запятая не нужна потому, что частица "даже" входит в состав деепричастного оборота.

Третья закрывает деепричастный оборот, четвёртая отделяет придаточное предложение.

***И даже приближаясь к звёздам, помни, что всегда можно подняться ещё выше!***

Comment: *Вопрос сформулирован вполне корректно - там ли и так ли расставлены запятые* - вопрос так не стоит. корректно или нет. Вопрос стоит, должны ли мы тут делать домашние задания за ленивых двоечников или помогать только тем, кто готов сам работать, но в чем-то пока разобрался. Вам, как человеку начавшему своё прибывание на ресурсе с обещания устроить нам всем тут веселую жизнь, давно пора это усвоить. Ну а в том, что Вы лично можете дать "правильный" ответ на "корректный вопрос", никто не сомневался.

Comment: *Обе запятые, обособляющие частицу "даже", не нужны.* - а откуда Вы знаете, что автор мотивирует эти запятые обособлением частицы "даже"? И что он вообще считает "даже" частицей, а не наречием, скажем? И где у него вообще границы деепричастного оборота? *"И даже ... [, приближаясь к звездам,]... помни, что всегда можно..."* - вот вам и вся "частица"